# How to use a variable in a LIKE query in Metabase?

Tags: sql, metabase

I have a column of string `kpi_date`, which follows the format of `dd-mm-yyyy`. I need to group the table on to each `kpi_date` within the month. I tried to use a `LIKE` query this way:

```
SELECT  
        kpi_date, sum(tickets)
FROM    
        database
    WHERE 
        client_id = {{client_id}} AND kpi_date LIKE "%"||{{month}}||"%"
GROUP BY   
        kpi_date
```

With the input variable being `month` (example: '11-2019', '12-2019', etc.)

The result is that Metabase printed out every single kpi_date within *every* month, regardless of what month I inputted to it. However, when I tried changing the related query to:

```
... AND kpi_date LIKE "%12-2019%"
```

it successfully printed out each kpi_date within that *specific* month.

What am I doing wrong with my variable usage?

Answer (score 2):

In which database you are used, if you use SQL server then query like below:

```
SELECT kpi_date, sum(tickets)
FROM database
WHERE client_id = @client_id AND kpi_date LIKE '%'+@month+'%'
GROUP BY kpi_date
```